# Windows 8 WinJS Sqlite

Tags: winjs

I want to implement windows 8 winjs sqlite in my application. What is the best approach to implement the sqlite in winjs windows 8 application? How to increase the app performance using sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this library for it: https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT

Answer (score 0):

There's a port of SQLite available on GitHub: https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

> sql.js is a port of SQLite to JavaScript, by compiling the SQLite C
>   code with Emscripten. no C bindings or node-gyp compilation here.

I firmly tested it and it works in WinJS Apps. The only things it lacks of course is any sort of Integration with WinJS because SQLite.js is also meant to be used in Browsers.

I don't have any info on Performance, you might have to test this on your own. As for best practices, you should probably build a "class" that wraps common functionality, like retrieving data with WHERE clauses and sanitizing Input before INSERTing.